# Why the Functions aren't defined ? PHP

Tags: php, oop, function

What do I have to do so that I can use the standard php functions without creating an instance of a Math_functions Class ?

```
<?php

    class Math_functions {

        public static function evenNumber($number) {
            return !($number & 1);
        }

        public static function natual_sum($n) {
            while ($n) {
                if (evenNumber($n)) {
                    $sum = $sum + $n;
                }
                $n--;
            }
            return $sum;
        }

    }

    echo natual_sum(4);
?>
```

Comment: echo `Math_functions::natural_sum(4);`

Answer (score 3):

This is a static function. You have to access it using class name. Use  like this

```
Math_functions::natual_sum(4);
```

Comment: He asked how to use them without using the class.

Comment: @God, no he ask how to use them without instantiating the class.

Comment: @God: To be specific, without *instantiating* the class.  The above doesn't instantiate it; it just calls the member function.

Comment: The omnipotent one has spoken.

Answer (score -4):

Just put the functions into a PHP File.

You don't *NEED* the class

Example:

```
<?php
        function evenNumber($number) {
            return !($number & 1);
        }

        function natual_sum($n) {
            while ($n) {
                if (evenNumber($n)) {
                    $sum = $sum + $n;
                }
                $n--;
            }
            return $sum;
        }

    echo natual_sum(4);
?>
```

Comment: You don't ever __need__ OO, but it's still worth learning as it facilitates writing good clean code... when someone is making the effort to learn, don't try to tell them they shouldn't

Comment: @MarkBaker - I agree, I only use OO, however I thought OP was asking how he can get away without having a class.

Comment: He was asking about referencing static functions (ie not needing to __instantiate__ a class)

Comment: I'm not sure these functions really belong in a class anyway, as there are no objects involved.